# What's the difference between keymaps - Mac OS X and Mac OS X 10.5+?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and learning shortcuts first to start my development actively in the IDE.

The default keymap scheme is `Mac OS X`.

What's the purpose of the other scheme `Mac OS X 10.5+`? Is this any better (or worse?) than the default one? I'd like to know how they compare and what the main differences are.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is the good explanation in help about the difference between two schemas:

1. the "Mac OS X 10.5+" schema is close to Mac OS default shortcuts. For example **cmd+G** is common Mac shortcut to find next matching text, **cmd+O** - open class - which is close to open action
2. the "IntelliJ IDEA Classic - Mac OS X 10.5" schema is close to IDEA shortcuts on other operation systems - Windows and Linux. For example **cmd+N** - open class - is close to **ctrl+N** to same option in Linux or Windows

Comment: Too bad new versions of PyCharm, which is based on IntelliJ, don't use the same new key mappings as IntelliJ.

Comment: n.b. There is now a **Mac OS 10.5+** keymap in Pycharm. Unfortunately, there is no option in Dataguard for same.

Answer (score 23):

The "10.5" keymap's *raison d'être* can be found in [a 2009 post by a JetBrains engineer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5251290):

> I want to introduce here a new keymap scheme that we created recently for Mac OS X users. The main reasons for doing this are:
>
> 1. More native key combinations for standard actions (e.g. Find, Find Next, Go to Line, Close Tab, etc.)
> 2. Less conflicts with the default system keybindings, such as Exposé (F9, F10, F11) and others.